# Add the first element to the Stream from the same Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Stream of JsonNode that I want to convert to Stream<String[]> like CSV, where the first row is headers and then we have values. The `TextDataUtils.sample` is expecting the same. I'm currently using `Stream.concat` to achieve this but the first row will always be `[]` because I'm extracting headers only after we start processing the values stream.

```java
    GoogleAdsGetValuesResponse getValuesResponse = client.getValues(getValuesRequest);
    AtomicLong consumedRows = new AtomicLong();
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    Stream<String[]> valueStream =
        getValuesResponse
            .getValuesStream()
            .limit(request.getLimit())
            .map(
                rowNode -> {
                  if (consumedRows.get() == 0) {
                    extractAllKeys(rowNode, "", headers);
                    headers.removeIf(header -> !header.contains("."));
                  }
                  String[] row =
                      headers.stream()
                          .map(header -> rowNode.at(getJsonPointerString(header)).asText())
                          .toArray(String[]::new);
                  consumedRows.getAndIncrement();
                  return row;
                });

    Stream<String[]> headerStream = Stream.of(headers.toArray(String[]::new), new String[] {});
    Stream<String[]> dataStream = Stream.concat(headerStream, valueStream);
    return TextDataUtils.sample(dataStream, Collections.emptyMap(), request.getLimit(), false);
```

How do I achieve this? Add the first element to the Stream from the same Stream. Appreciate any suggestions. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier (both to read and to write) if you *don't* use streams. How about doing the mapping and concatenating part with array lists instead?

Comment: @Sweeper we are dealing with huge amount of data, so streaming is necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not allow you to alter collections while iterating over them, so what you want to do is not possible.

I would suggest first processing the headers with `limit(1)` and then proceed to concatenate that with the remaining processed items using `skip(1)`.

Roughly:

```
Stream<String> headerStream = newResponseStream.limit(1).getHeaders()
Stream<String[]> valueStream = newResponseStream.skip(1).getRows()

Stream<String[]> dataStream = Stream.concat(headerStream, valueStream);
return TextDataUtils.sample(dataStream, Collections.emptyMap(), request.getLimit(), false);
```

Note that you cannot reuse the starting response stream.  This will still be efficient if the underlying stream is properly lazily fetching.

As a side note, I would avoid writing map functions with side effects.  It makes the code more difficult to reason about.